# Adding hours to get the total hours as result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<input type ="text" name="txt1" class="cl_tot_st">

<input type ="text" name="txt5" class="cl_tot_st">

<input type ="text" id="gtot_st">
```

I need sum of hours that I  enter in textboxes which are in a common class names `cl_tot_st`
I need the result in a text box whose id id `gtot_st`
I used this function for to get the result. But, nothing happening when I run the code.

```
function grand_total(){
  var t1 = "00.00";
  var mins = 0;
  var hrs = 0;
    $(".cl_tot_st").each(function () {
        t1 = t1.split('.');
        var t2 = $(this).val().split('.');
        console.log(Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]))
        mins = Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]);
        minhrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
        hrs = Number(t1[0]) + Number(t2[0]) + minhrs;
        mins = mins % 60;
        t1 = hrs.padDigit() + '.' + mins.padDigit()
        console.log(t1)
    });
    $('#gtot_st').text(t1);
};
```

i found this code from here
http://jsfiddle.net/7ov9hL8k/

Comment: How do you run `grand_total()`?

Comment: add `onclick=grand_total()` so that the function will work.

Comment: but i need it like when i enter a value in one text box the grantotal will automatically appear in gtot_st text box

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned that in the question? You need to listen for changes in the input values. For example, use `onchange=grand_total()` for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?:

I've replaced the label with a text box and I've added an `input` event listener for the "time" text boxes. Whenever you make a change in any one of the time text boxes, the times will be re-calculated.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ov9hL8k/16/)

**Html:**

```
<input id="time1" value="1.45" size="5" class="time">Time 1
<br>
<input id="time2" value="1.30" size="5" class="time">Time 2
<br>
<input id="time2" value="1.32" size="5" class="time">Time 3
<br>
<input id="time2" value="5.30" size="5" class="time">Time 4

<br><button id="addTimes">Add times</button>
<br><br>Result<span id="timeSum"><input type ="text" id="gtot_st"></span>

<br>
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
Number.prototype.padDigit = function () {
  return (this < 10) ? '0' + this : this;
}

function CalculateTotal() {
  var t1 = "00.00";
  var mins = 0;
  var hrs = 0;
  $('input.time').each(function () {
    t1 = t1.split('.');
    var t2 = $(this).val().split('.');
    console.log(Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]))
    mins = Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]);
    minhrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
    hrs = Number(t1[0]) + Number(t2[0]) + minhrs;
    mins = mins % 60;
    t1 = hrs.padDigit() + '.' + mins.padDigit()
    console.log(t1);
  });
  return t1;
}

$("#addTimes").on('click', function () {
  $('#gtot_st').val(CalculateTotal());
});

//Check for an input change on any one of the text boxes with a class of "time"
$(".time").on('input', function() {
    $('#gtot_st').val(CalculateTotal());
})
```

Comment: can i use '.' instead of ':' ?